# How to populate a drop down menu with file names from a directory as options using PHP?

Tags: php, html, file, drop-down-menu, directory

I'm trying to create a drop down menu that points to a directory and populates a drop down menu with the names of certain files in that directory using PHP.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
<?php

$path = "pages/"; //change this if the script is in a different dir that the files you want
$show = array( '.php', '.html' ); //Type of files to show

$select = "<select name=\"content\" id=\"content\">";

$dh = @opendir( $path );

while( false !== ( $file = readdir( $dh ) ) ){
    $ext=substr($file,-4,4);
        if(in_array( $ext, $show )){       
            $select .= "<option value='$path/$file'>$file</option>\n";
    }
}  

$select .= "</select>";
closedir( $dh );

echo "$select";
?>
```

This bit of code is giving me an errors, and I'm not even really attached to it if there's a better way of trying to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: readdir(): supplied argument is not a valid Directory Resource in ... on line ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to use [glob()](http://us.php.net/glob) because it can handle wildcards.

```
// match all files that have either .html or .php extension
$file_matcher = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/../pages/*.{php,html}';

foreach( glob($file_matcher, GLOB_BRACE) as $file ) {
  $file_name = basename($file);
  $select .= "<option value='$file'>$file_name</option>\n";
}
```

Comment: This got me a drop down menu, but was populated with files from the directory of the php script, instead of the directory I want.

Comment: @antiquarichat what is `$path` set to?

Comment: I have the php script in http://url.com/admin/... I want it to point to http://url.com/pages/... and that's basically what I have it set to. $path = "http://url.com/pages/";

Comment: @antiquarichat take a look at my update and see if that fixes the problem

Comment: Getting closer, it's pointing to the right directory... The whole path including the file name is being given as values for each option. I just need the filename to show.

Comment: @antiquarichat I updated by answer to use `basename()` so only the filename is shown.

Answer (score 1):

You need a full path reference (i.e. /var/www/pages/) instead of just "pages".

Also you might consider using DirectoryIterator object for easily getting to directroy information (if you are using PHP 5).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, which errors you get. But I think it won't work with the `$show` array because you're comparing the last 4 chars of the file with the contents of the array. Instead of `$ext=substr($file,-4,4);` you could write `$ext=substr($file, strrpos( $file, "."));` which gives you the string from the position of the last occurance of ".".

Also I suggest for test reason that you omit the @ opening the directory because I think that the path cannot be found.